# GitLab Using $CI_ENVIRONMENT_NAME with rules:changes fails

Tags: gitlab

$CI_ENVIRONMENT_NAME doesn't work with rules:changes. Is it expected behaviour?

```
rules:
    - changes:  # Include the job and set to when:manual if any of the follow paths match a modified file.
      - authurl/config/$CI_ENVIRONMENT_NAME/*
      when: manual
      allow_failure: false
```

As soon as the variable replaced with a static value the rule stars working.

Answer (score 0):

The [docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html) mention that `$CI_ENVIRONMENT_NAME` is available only if `environment:name` is set.

For expected behavior, you might have to add the environment value to the job.